# Why can I show data in emulator from MySQL database but not retrieve in on phones?

Tags: android, mysql

I retrieved data from MySQl database. It is shown in the emulator, but not on the device.

Please tell why this problem is happening and how I should solve it

[image: Emulator]
[image: Device]

Comment: Where is your database? Is it an SQLite database on your device or is it a database you access via network?

Comment: it is in my device, it is mysql database using wampserver.  i can show data when i run in emulator. but not show when in run in my android device.

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator can easily access database which is in mysql and through xampp server. because your xampp server is available only for your computer. if you want to make it accessible to all devices then you need to put your databse to server.

Comment: okkk but, but before buy web host server, i try how to work my project. on mobile phones.

Comment: you need to make your server accessible to your smart phone.